# Continuously compounding interest with change of rate at a certain value

Tags: calculus

I've been thinking about continuous interest where the rate changes with *value*, and not with *time*. i.e. Interest rate is 2% for the first \$10,000 (that's just a standard compound interest formula) and then 1% for all values after that (that's a combination of the simple interest formula and the compound interest formula). It's not too hard to do for the cases before \$10,000, or after \$10,000. But I am struggling to think of a way to do it with one formula to apply to a balance that will account for the change in interest rate over all time.

Is this a solvable problem? My bank pays out in a manner similar to this, and I wanted to build a small tool to calculate what my balance would be given a starting balance and a time period, or a ticker to show my instantaneous balance given the interest rates and my starting balance, from now.

I could, I suppose, calculate at which time, $t$, the balance crosses over \$10,000, and switch formulas for $t$ before and after that, but it would be cool if there was a single step function which could apply across the whole balance. There might be a way to integrate across the range that I'm not seeing, either.

I have looked at https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/alina.vdovina/teaching/2011-mas1243/notes-lecturer.pdf (section 7.4) but that only works for a rate varying with time, not with value. There seems to be a fair bit around changing over time, but almost nothing (that I've found) about changing with value.

Comment: A piecewise definition will suffice (and is necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Let the balance be $B$, which we will assume is over $10k$ for now.  The easy way to think of it is as $1\%$ interest plus a bonus of $100/$year due to the extra interest.  This gives $$\frac {dB}{dt}=.01B+100\\B=B_0e^{.01t}+100t$$
where $B_0$ is the starting balance.  Of course, if $B_0$ is less than $10k$ it is just $B=B_0e^{0.02t}$ until the balance is $10k$ and you reset $B_0$ and switch over then.

Comment: okay, but if, say, i have a balance of \$9,900 now, and want to know the balance in 3 years, i would have to "stop" when it gets to \$10,000 and then restart. I'm after 1 formula that i can apply the balance and the time to and get an output, more or less.

Comment: Why would you expect one formula when the rules change midway?  Compute the time for the balance to reach 10k from the second formula, then start to use the first.